# angular 2 application being replaced by another webpage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have been working on an angular 2 project learning from this tutorial http://courses.angularclass.com/p/angular-2-fundamentals

as soon as i run my api with `npm run api` on localhost:3000
the whole application gets replaced by another webpage

[image]

and my package.json is:

```
{


    "name": "retain",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "webpack --config webpack.spec.ts --progress --color && karma start",
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --colors --progress --display-error-details --display-cached --port 3000  --content-base src",
        "api": "angularclass-server --api retain --port 3000"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "^2.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "^2.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^2.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "^2.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "^3.0.0",
        "@angularclass/api": "^1.2.0",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "lodash": "^4.16.1",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-rc.4",
        "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@types/core-js": "^0.9.33",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.35",
        "@types/node": "^6.0.39",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.0.0-beta.10",
        "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
        "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
        "karma": "^1.1.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^1.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
        "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.4",
        "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
        "to-string-loader": "^1.1.4",
        "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
        "typescript": "^2.1.4",
        "webpack": "^1.14.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
      }

}
```

please tell if I need to add anything else to identify this error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "api": "angularclass-server --api retain --port 3000" to your localhost

Comment: could you elaborate more?

Comment: to start the app you need to do npm run start.
Feathers is altogether different thing

Comment: that image is the screenshot of the webpage i receive once i type `npm run api` and open localhost:3000 in my browser, I even tried `npm run start` but it results in an error.

Comment: Your **package.json** is wrong, the line should be `"api": "angularclass-server --api retain --port 3500"` Then you need to run this command `npm run api` (this will start the rest api on port 3500) then in **an other terminal** you need to run this command `npm run start` (this will start the angular 2 app on port 3000). Then you open localhost:3000 in your browser

Answer (score 0):

As per package JSON

there are 2 scripts.
 1. npm run start : run the angular 2 application
 2. npm run api : it creates a seperate feathers project, used for Rest API, you can find more abt that module on https://www.npmjs.com/package/feathers

so for angular 2 if u need some rest API , u can create in the feathers project & Then consume it in angular 2 Application